# variable is assigned a value but never used except it actually is used

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I am working with Vue.js and it is complaining about a variable being declared but never used. Only issue is it is actually being used just below where I declare it except it is inside a forEach loop where it's used. Essentially I am trying to use nested forEach loops and have two different counts come back so I can display it on my front end.

Method that isn't working

```
formatData() {
 this.trucks.forEach(truck => {
   truck.barCount = truck.bar.length
   let fooCounter = 0
   truck.tenantCount = truck.bar.forEach(unit => {
     fooCounter += bar.foo.length
   })
 });
}
```

Error message:

```
error  'fooCounter' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Comment: You only initialise and increment it, but you never actually *use* the result for anything. Do that and the eslint warning will disappear.

Comment: the message is right, you're not using it... and BTW, why assign a variable `truck.tenantCount`  to void? as void is what `forEach` returns...

Comment: @Bergi I hadn't gotten that far yet before Vue started complaining about it being broken. Just tried going forward adding in the next step it now works.

Comment: @balexandre Didn't know it returns as void, I had never tried it before and figured it might work but that is good to know. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying `fooCounter += bar.foo.length` is a use? It's not a use, it doesn't affect anything. If you removed that line, how would your app's behavior be affected? Unless the value of `fooCounter` is actually used somewhere else, removing `fooCounter` wouldn't affect your app's behavior at all.

> Essentially I am trying to use nested forEach loops and have two different counts come back so I can display it on my front end.

Once you start displaying `fooCounter` somewhere, that will count as a use, and that error message will go away.

Comment: See that now, I just replied to Bergi and he said it doesn't count too. I went ahead and added the next part of what I was planning on and it works. Guess shouldn't be looking at the vue output when working on a function

Comment: @joshk132 definitely kinda weird and annoying that `no-unused-vars` is an error rather than a warning